# Subadditive sequence implies $\lim s_n/n$ exists.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I prove that for a subadditive sequence the next limit $$\lim s_n/n$$ exists where $s_n$ is subadditive?

PS
I can see that $s_n/n$ is subadditive as well, but I don't see how to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(u_n)$ be a subadditive sequence and $n>p$ two positive intergers. In particular, $n=kp+r$ for some $0 \leq r \leq p-1$. Therefore

$$\frac{u_n}{n} = \frac{u_{kp+r}}{kp+r} \leq \frac{u_{kp}}{kp+r} + \frac{u_r}{n} \leq \frac{u_{kp}}{kp} + \frac{u_r}{n}.$$

It is clear that $u_{kp} \leq k \cdot u_p$, hence $\displaystyle \frac{u_n}{n} \leq \frac{u_{p}}{p}+ \frac{u_r}{n}$. Therefore,

$$\limsup\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{u_n}{n} \leq \inf\limits_{p \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{u_p}{p} \leq \liminf\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{u_n}{n}.$$

We conclude that $$\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{u_n}{n} = \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{u_n}{n}.$$

Notice that the limit may be $- \infty$, for example if $u_n=-n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
http://math.nyu.edu/degree/undergrad/Chen.pdf

Apparently I know the result already from Kingman's theorem.